# some phenomena about Fibonacci number

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-residues

**Edit:** for conjecture 3, define :$(\frac{5}{F_n}) = 5 ^{\frac{F_n-1}2} mod     (F_n)$, $F_n $ is odd number.

When study Fibonacci number,  some phenomena are observed：

1. $(\frac{F_p}{5})= (\frac{p}{5}) $ for all odd primes $p$, $(\frac{p}{5})$ is Legendre symbol. (verified for $p < 10 ^ 8$)
2. All divisors of $F_p$ have the form of  $2px + (-1)^x$, where $p$ is prime.

   It's known that for odd $n$, all divisors of $F_n$ have the form of $2nx \pm1.$
3. If $(\frac{F_n}{5})= (\frac{5}{F_n})$, then $F_n$ is odd prime. (Verified for $n < 40000$)

   It seems that could be generalized for all Lucas sequence $ Un(P,Q)$ and  $Vn(P,Q), D = P^2-4Q$: if $ (\frac{L_n}{D}) = (\frac{D}{L_n})$, and D is prime with form of 4k+1, then $L_n $ is odd prime.

Could you explain one of them?

Comment: 1 can be proven straightforwardly. The behavior of $Fn$ (assuming that this means the $n$-th Fibonacci number) modulo $5$ is periodic with period $20$, so you only need to check the first $20$ Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: And of course, (1) holds for all odd $p$, prime or not.

Comment: 3 seems to fail for $n=8$ already, in which case $F_n = 21, \left( \frac{F_n}{5} \right) = 1$ and $\left( \frac{5}{F_n} \right) = \left( \frac{5}{3} \right) \left( \frac{5}{7} \right) = 1$, yet $F_n$ is evidently not an odd prime.

Comment: @Ofir Gorodetsky  Let me check my sage Program to see if I missed something

Comment: @shenlixing In fact, quadratic reciprocity for the Jacobi symbol shows that $\left( \frac{F_n}{5} \right) = \left( \frac{5}{F_n} \right)$ whenever $\gcd(F_n, 10)=1$, which is the same as $\gcd(n,15)=1$. When $n$ is divisible by $5$, this also holds, since $F_n \equiv 0 \bmod 5$ and so $\left( \frac{F_n}{5} \right) = 0, \left( \frac{5}{F_n} \right)=0$.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky I found the key point: forget the definition of symbol.